# Use of Aura.Action attribute to stop the refresh in my parent component from my child component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have the cancel function in my child component which actually closes the overlay in my parent component where I have a refresh action which refreshes the page after I cancel the action. I have read about Aura.Action attribute but I am confused on how to use it my child component.

ChildComponent.cmp

```
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overLayLib"/>
<div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer slds-size_1-of-1">
            <lightning:button type="button" variant="neutral" label="{!$Label.c.Button_Cancel}" 
                              onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
            <lightning:button type="submit" variant="brand" label="{!$Label.c.Button_Save}"/>
        </div>
```

ChildComponent.js

```
cancel: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("overLayLib").notifyClose();
},
```

ParentComponent.js

```
 showEditOverlay : function(component) {
            var modalBody;
            const opportunityId = component.get('v.recordId');
            const Details = component.get("v.DetailData");
            $A.createComponent("c:Details",{DetailData:Details, opportunityId:opportunityId},
                               function(content, status) {
                                   if(status === "SUCCESS"){
                                       modalBody = content;
                                       component.find('overLayLib').showCustomModal({
                                           header: $A.get("$Label.c.Details"),
                                           body: modalBody,
                                           showCloseButton:false,
                                           closeCallback: function(result) {
                                               console.log('showEditOverlay :: closeCallback :: ',  result);
                                               $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                                           }
                                       })
                                   }
                               });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your code ,your child component `cancel` button click event doesn't call parent component `closeCallback` function. there is 2 ways to call parent and close the modal popup.
1. create the event and fire at child then then catch that event in parent then close the modal pop like below code.
2. dynamically create the button component and set the `component.getreference` and add in to foot component body

**Actionevent.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Actionevent">   
    <aura:attribute name="actionname" type="String"></aura:attribute>
</aura:event>
```

**child.cmp**

```
<aura:registerEvent name="Actionname" type="c:Actionevent"></aura:registerEvent>

<div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer slds-size_1-of-1">
            <lightning:button type="button" variant="neutral" label="{!$Label.c.Button_Cancel}" 
                              onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
            <lightning:button type="submit" variant="brand" label="{!$Label.c.Button_Save}"/>
        </div>
```

**childcontroller.Js**

```
cancel: function (component, event, helper) {
    var actionEvt = $A.get("e.c:Actionevent");
            actionEvt.setParams({
                "actionname": 'Close'
            });
            actionEvt.fire();
},
```

**parent.cmp**

```
<aura:attribute name="modalProm" type="Aura.Action"/>
 <aura:handler event="c:Actionevent" action="{!c.closeactionevt}"/>
```

**parentcontroller.js**

```
showEditOverlay : function(component) {
            var modalBody;
            const opportunityId = component.get('v.recordId');
            const Details = component.get("v.DetailData");
            $A.createComponent("c:Details",{DetailData:Details, opportunityId:opportunityId},
                               function(content, status) {
                                   if(status === "SUCCESS"){
                                       modalBody = content;
                                     var promaction =  component.find('overLayLib').showCustomModal({
                                           header: $A.get("$Label.c.Details"),
                                           body: modalBody,
                                           showCloseButton:false,
                                           closeCallback: function(result) {
                                               console.log('showEditOverlay :: closeCallback :: ',  result);
                                               $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                                           }
                                       });
                   component.set("v.modalProm",promaction);
                                   }
                               });
        },
closeactionevt : function(cmp,evt){
  if(event.getParam("actionname") === 'close'){
      component.get("v.modalProm").then(function (modal){
                modal.close();
            });
     };

 }
```